# Mapping over 3D imagery

Tags: 3d, stereo-imagery, arcgis-stereo-analyst

Most 3D visualisation solutions I've seen are drapes of imagery over a surface like a TIN.  Is there any open source software out there that can permit viewing of 3D data (e.g. Leica ADS data) and creation of a terrain following vector layer similar to what the Stereoanalyst plug-in for ArcGIS does and which doesn't cost a lot?